# XMLHttpRequest returning undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i'm trying to send this HTTP request through my function but it returns undefined no matter what

it's a very basic request and i don't understand why this is happening

if i copy and paste the URL into my browser it works and shows the desired JSON

i tried this function on my browser's console using random id and my api key and still return undefined all the same

```
function getSummary(id){
    let url2=`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/summary?apiKey=${key}`;
    let xhr2=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.responseType='json';
    xhr2.onreadystatechange=()=>{
        if(xhr2.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            return xhr2.response;
        }
    }
    
    xhr2.open('GET',url2);
    xhr2.send();
}
```

[link to the API's doc](https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Summarize-Recipe)

Comment: i include it in the url as instructed by the API's documentation, again: pasting the url in my browser's url bar returns the desired result but the http request in my function doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the return statement inside of an arrow function and it does not return out of the main function.

```
xhr2.onreadystatechange=()=>{
  //returns out of this function ^
  if(xhr2.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    return xhr2.response;
  }
}
```

Instead of creating a function to return the response text you need to run a function with the response text as an argument:

```
let url2=`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/summary?apiKey=${key}`;
let xhr2=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.responseType='json';
xhr2.onreadystatechange=()=>{
  if(xhr2.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
       //seperate function
       run(xhr2.response);
    }
  }    
xhr2.open('GET',url2);
xhr2.send();

function run(text){
  console.log(text);
};
```